# Is this result for regular expression backreferencing correct?

Tags: javascript, python, regex, mongodb

I used Javascript in the command line client of MongoDB v2.2.4 to run the following regular expression backreferencing:

```js
> /([AB])([AB])/("BA")
[ "BA", "B", "A" ]
```

I had thought I should get ["B","A"] but I got an extra element "BA" at the beginning of the array. I tried the same regular expression backreferencing in Python, the returning results is what I expected as follows:

```py
>>> re.search('([AB])([AB])','BA').groups()
('B', 'A')
```

So, may I say the result of the regular expression backreferencing from Javascript in MongoDB is wrong?

Comment: Please post text not images.

Comment: Also, there is no backreferencing taking place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MongoDB result includes the whole matched string, or group 0, as well as groups 1 and 2.

The Python `.groups()` method only returns captured groups. The `.group()` method would, without an argument, return group 0 too:

```
>>> re.search('([AB])([AB])', 'BA').groups()
('B', 'A')
>>> re.search('([AB])([AB])', 'BA').group()
'BA'
>>> re.search('([AB])([AB])', 'BA').group(1)
'B'
>>> re.search('([AB])([AB])', 'BA').group(2)
'A'
>>> re.search('([AB])([AB])', 'BA').group(0)
'BA'
```

This is [documented in the `re` module documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.groups):

> Return a tuple containing all the subgroups of the match, from 1 up to however many groups are in the pattern.

and for the `.group()` method:

> Returns one or more subgroups of the match. If there is a single argument, the result is a single string; if there are multiple arguments, the result is a tuple with one item per argument. Without arguments, *group1* defaults to zero (the whole match is returned).

Note that there are no back-references in your expression. A back-reference would look like this instead:

```
'([AB])\1'
```

where the `\1` refers to the capturing group just before it. The back-reference will only match the exact same characters that the referenced group matched.

Demo:

```
>>> re.search(r'([AB])\1', 'BA')
>>> re.search(r'([AB])\1', 'BB')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x107098210>
```

Note how only `BB` is matched, *not* `BA`.

You can use named groups too:

```
'(?P<a_or_b>[AB])(?P=a_or_b)'
```

where `a_or_b` is the group name.

Comment: Thank you for your explaination for back-references. In the demo, we can also write the regular expression as re.search(r'([AB]){2}','BB') if we do not want to use back-references, right?

Answer (score 3):

In JavaScript (and many other Regex engines) Group 0 is considered the whole input, while matching groups start at 1.  In Python's re module the groups start at 0, because the whole string is your input.

Comment: for what it's worth I think Python's approach makes more sense, I think the old behavior has survived so long because Regular expressions look like black magic to most people, so breaking code related to them is extra scary.